# How to Get the DataType of excel cell value using nodejs version16.14.2 and Vue js

Tags: node.js, excel, vue.js, vuex, exceljs

**I need to get the DataType value of each cell record of an Excel sheet using Node.js version 16.14.2 and Vue js.** Can you please help me out how can I get the value of the DataType of each cell in the excel sheet? I am using Visual Studio Code editor. PFA as highlighted from where we can select the DataType of a cell record in excel. Please let me know with this information as soon as possible. [image: Image1]. [image: Image2]

Comment: That's not the data type, that's the number format.

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried with the following: I have tried with node-xlsx package , I have tried with exceljs npm package , I have tried with xlsx npm package. But nothing is working to get the type of cell data that is selected from Dropdown.

Comment: I have just given an example where I have selected 'Number' , 'General' type to that particular cell value from the dropdown, it can be any other type as well that can be selected from that dropdown. I need to get that type that I have selected for that cell in excel in my node js code. Could you please let me know on this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this dependency [conver-excel-to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-excel-to-json)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).